# ToolStripManager.Merge corrupts button?

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net, I have 2 contextmenustrips: cmsSource and cmsMain.

I am merging cmsSource into cmsMain so I can have another contextmenu drop down like this:

```
ToolStripManager.Merge(cmsSource,cmsMain)
```

I am still using cmsSource to assign to a splitbutton:

```
splitbutton.ContextMenuStrip = cmsSource
```

But when I run the code, the splitbutton will not show the contextmenu when clicked. If I comment out the ToolStripManager.Merge function, it works fine. Also, I try to assign the splitbutton prior to merging but that also does not work. BTW, cmsMain has 2 submenus containing ToolStripMenuItems and cmsSource has 1 submenu containing ToolStripMenuItems.

I have also set cmsmain.allowmerge = true, that did not help. If I merge and revertmerge, it works as if I never merged(obviously). So does the merging somehow alter cmsSource or keep it from being used? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but I think that's just the way it is, once it is merged, cmsSource cannot be used. I'll just duplicate the cms.